# Mermaid - How to set the labels style for flowchart nodes

Tags: flowchart, mermaid

I need to change the style of the flowchart nodes.
I've managed to set the background color and the outline:

```
style s1 fill:#0000,stroke:#333,stroke-width:2px
```

However, I do not see how can I control the labels, e.g. set the font color, font family, bold, underline, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML page, add custom styles that target `div.mermaid`. For example:

```
div.mermaid {
   font-family: 'trebuchet ms', verdana, arial;
   font-size: 30px; 
}
```